# Session store not set on request Laravel 11

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-11

I'm attempting to implement basic authentication functionality for testing purposes. I'm testing via Postman, so before logging in, I make a GET request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie`. After that, I hit the `/login` endpoint and am able to receive data (if this part `$request->session()->regenerate();` is commented out). However, if I try to access a protected route, I receive an error. Despite following the documentation closely, I'm encountering an issue when a user attempts to sign in. I receive an error when `$request->session()->regenerate();` this is not commented out:

```
"message": "Session store not set on request."
```

Here's my bootstrap/app.php:

```
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        using: function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->group(function () {
                    // routes/api.php is not included here
                    require base_path('routes/Api/V1/Auth/routes.php');
                });
        },
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->statefulApi();
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();
```

Here's my login:

```
public function login(object $request)
    {
        // Validate user credentials
        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only(['username', 'password']))) {
            return $this->failedRequest('', 'Invalid email address or password', 400);
        }

        // Regenerate the user's session to prevent session fixation
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        // Sign in user
        Auth::login(Auth::user());

        // Return data
        return $this->successfullRequest(Auth::user(), 'User successfully logged in', 200);
    }
```

My routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/auth'], function () {
    Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
});
```

If I remove this part, I basically receive Unauthenticated message when I try to hit .../logout

> $request->session()->regenerate();

sanctum.php -> stateful:

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''))),
```

my env file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:5000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: laravel sanctum is a token based authenticaiton not a session based 
the overflow for sanctum is pretty staight froward
you attempt the login as you did after that you need to create a token for that user and then you need to send it as a response to the front end and then from the front end you need to add it with in the headers with all the request that will be added in your sanctum middleware

Comment: there is no use session when it comes to sanctum
read the documentaion if it not makes sense commend again ^^

Comment: @Harris are you sure? "For this feature, Sanctum does not use tokens of any kind. Instead, Sanctum uses Laravel's built-in cookie based session authentication services. " https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sanctum#spa-authentication